# How to label a dataset of text pairs to use it as a universal one for calculating the precision@k metric for different models?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, transformer, metric, search

I am facing a semantic search problem. I am fine tuning different NLU models and i want to use precision@k as my main metric. Is it possible to label a dataset of text pairs to use it as a universal one for calculating the precision@k metric for different NLU models? Or the only way is to label dataset after semantic search all over again for each model?